# Get row index by column value in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i get the index of a datagridview row by column value of that row ? And also , how can i update the datagridview when a value of a column has been changed ?

Comment: Is this WPF? Is your `DataGridView` data-bound to a collection?

Comment: yes it's WPF and the datagridview is updated by button clicks!

Comment: Wait… WPF doesn’t have `DataGridView`. I assume you’re on Windows Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re comment -- find which rows contain a value of x:

Should be something like this (not tested)

```
List<int> rowsOfInterest = new List<int>();

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
  if (row.Cells["Column I want"].Value == ValueIWant)
    rowsOfInterest.Add(row.Index);
```

---

I think what you want is this, but your question is not 100% clear.

```
foreach(object value in dgv.Rows[rowindex].Cells)
   // check is value is one needed
```

Comment: i want the rowIndex by cell value !

Comment: Then maybe something along the lines of, for (int x = 0; x < dgr.Rows.Count; x++) --- and then check each dvg.Rows[x] for the column value you're looking for.  If you find it, save the value of x, because that will tell you what row you're in when you found it, else x++.....But like Hogan said, not 100% clear :) Good luck.